# Why are holidays stretched to the weekends?

Tags: time-off, holidays

Someone asked me why holidays are stretched into the weekends (like holiday on a thursday but you don't go friday) and I'm not too sure why they do it, since it would be non beneficial to the company, right? Does anyone know how to explain it? Thanks!!

Comment: What is your location?  That's not a thing I've seen in the US.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek My experience has been the opposite, most places I've worked give the day after Thanksgiving (a Friday) as a holiday, and I've occasionally gotten the day before/after July 4 or Christmas as a holiday if they fall on a Tuesday/Thursday.

Comment: @NuclearWang Oh right, Thanksgiving.  For the other two, I've not gotten extra days, but people do take vacation for them.  Or the company has floating holidays and designates them instead of letting people choose, but they never just give additional paid holidays.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek some companies have a set number of holiday days per year, and some of those days go towards turning a holiday into a holiday weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nobody does much real work anyway**

The holidays which are on a date rather than the closest Friday/Monday (Canada Day or Christmas) are days when people have their minds on other things. My team had work on Christmas Eve. Did we accomplish anything that day? No, we did not. Lots of companies just acknowledge that reality.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: such is a tradition and/or [local regulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Russia#New_Year_Holiday) (laws). There is no deeper reason.

Any other answer will probably make things up, for example:

> it would be non beneficial to the company

Giving people more rest days might increase productivity, and [workers prefer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiFmKO3o6fnAhW0OH0KHWx5DrEQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.weforum.org%2Fagenda%2F2018%2F09%2Fa-four-day-working-week-on-full-pay-technological-advances-could-make-it-possible%2F&psig=AOvVaw1fqFeJzjqed12yGbvR9dKJ&ust=1580334627653121) 4-day weekends.